# PHP pages - Trying to run file on browser

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I'm new to PHP, so apologies for my question:

I've created three basic files in PHP as follows:

HT Docs folder
 Social Network PHP
 - create_account.php 
 - login.php 
 - index.php

When I try to locate the files, by typing "localhost" in my browser, the only file I can see on my browser files is index.php. Why I can't see other files?

Cheers

Bren

Comment: did you try localhost/login.php?

Comment: Is your url ok? Something like http://localhost/create_account.php?

Comment: Are you trying to write only localhost/ or localhost/login.php?

Comment: Is there a space in your directory name?

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache? remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: I'm using apache and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder inside HTDOCS folder, the move all the files into the created folder.

htdocs/myproject

Then access it with on your browser:

```
localhost/myproject/create_account.php

localhost/myproject/index.php

localhost/myproject/login.php
```

Comment: i tried this but guesing something wrong with my code - cheers for help